# iPhone:upload audio file to server using ASIHTTPREQUEST

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, asihttprequest

I want to upload audio file on the dedicated server and for that

I am using following code

```
NSURL *audiourl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"my Url"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:audiourl];
NSData *postData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
//url is my audio url path of NSDocumentDirectory.
[request addData:postData withFileName:@"myAudio.caf" andContentType:@"audio/caf" forKey:@"company_audio"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startSynchronous];
```

I print my url in console which gives me path as follows:

```
url:file://localhost/Users/User/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/013AE2E8-C410-4544-A426-D0706BC0A13A/Documents/myaudio.caf
```

but I don't see my audio file on server.

so what is the problem with my code?

any help would be appreciable.

thanx in advance...

Comment: what is your server side code?

Comment: Your code looks correct can you please give permission to server for read/write i think this may prevent to write audio file on server. Can you paste your response here after calling above code.